# GWT ScrollPanel did not work properly inside DialogBox

Tags: gwt

I would like to create dialogbox as below ...

```
public final class ChatDialog extends DialogBox {
private TextBox txtInputMsg;
private ScrollPanel pnlScroll;
private VerticalPanel pnlMessage;
private HorizontalPanel pnlMembers;
static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ChatDialog.class.getName());
private VerticalPanel pnlMain = new VerticalPanel();

private static final ChatMessageTemplate TEMPLATES = GWT.create(ChatMessageTemplate.class);
private AtmosphereRequest rpcRequest;
private AuthenticatedUser loginUser;

public ChatDialog() {
    super(false, false);
    setAnimationEnabled(true);
    setGlassEnabled(false);
    // Create anchor we want to accept click events
    final Anchor closeButton = new Anchor("x");
    closeButton.setStyleName("dialogCloseButton");

    // Add handler to anchor
    closeButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        public void onClick(final ClickEvent event) {
            hide();
        }
    });
    final HTML caption = ((HTML) getCaption());
    final Element title = DOM.createLabel();
    title.setInnerText("Chat");

    // Add anchor to caption
    caption.getElement().appendChild(title);
    caption.getElement().appendChild(closeButton.getElement());

    // Add click handler to caption
    caption.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        public void onClick(final ClickEvent event) {
            // Get x,y caption click relative to the anchor
            final int x = event.getRelativeX(closeButton.getElement());
            final int y = event.getRelativeY(closeButton.getElement());

            // Check click was within bounds of anchor
            if (x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x <= closeButton.getOffsetWidth()
                    && y <= closeButton.getOffsetHeight()) {
                // Raise event on anchor
                closeButton.fireEvent(event);
            }
        }
    });
    pnlMembers = new HorizontalPanel();
    pnlMembers.setWidth("400px");
    pnlMembers.add(ChatMembers.getInstance());
    pnlMessage = new VerticalPanel();
    pnlMessage.setWidth("100%");
    pnlScroll = new ScrollPanel(pnlMessage);
    pnlScroll.getElement().setAttribute("style", "border: 1px solid silver;"
            + "padding: 2px;margin-bottom: 5px;");
    pnlScroll.setSize("400px", "420px");
     pnlMain.add(pnlMembers);
    // contents panel
    pnlMain.add(pnlScroll);
    // footer control panel
    pnlMain.add(initFooterPanel());
    add(pnlMain);
}

private HorizontalPanel initFooterPanel() {
    HorizontalPanel pnlControl = new HorizontalPanel();
    pnlControl.getElement().setAttribute("style", "margin-top: 5px;");

    txtInputMsg = new TextBox();
    txtInputMsg.setWidth("400px");
    txtInputMsg.addKeyDownHandler(new KeyDownHandler() {

        public void onKeyDown(final KeyDownEvent event) {
            if (event.getNativeKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER) {
                if (txtInputMsg.getText().trim().length() > 0) {
                    try {
                        ChatEvent e = new ChatEvent(loginUser.getUserName(), txtInputMsg.getText(), Status.ONLINE);
                        rpcRequest.push(e);
                    }
                    catch (SerializationException ex) {
                        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Failed to serialize message", ex);
                    }
                    txtInputMsg.setText("");
                    txtInputMsg.setFocus(true);
                }
            }
        }

    });

    pnlControl.add(txtInputMsg);
    return pnlControl;
}

public void init(final AuthenticatedUser loginUser) {
    this.loginUser = loginUser;
    ChatMembers.getChatMembers();
    initChatListener();
    setPopupPositionAndShow(new PositionCallback() {

        public void setPosition(final int offsetWidth, final int offsetHeight) {
            setPopupPosition(getParent().getOffsetWidth() - getOffsetWidth() - 20,
                    getParent().getOffsetHeight() - getOffsetHeight());
        }

    });
    show();

}

private DialogCloseHandler handler;

public void addDialogCloseHandler(final DialogCloseHandler handler) {
    this.handler = handler;
}

public interface DialogCloseHandler {
    void onUpdate();
    void onCancel();
}

public void onSave() {
}

public void onEscape() {
    hide();
    handler.onCancel();
}

private void initChatListener() {
    RPCSerializer rpcSerializer = GWT.create(RPCSerializer.class);

    AtmosphereRequestConfig rpcRequestConfig = AtmosphereRequestConfig.create(rpcSerializer);
    rpcRequestConfig.setUrl(GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "atmosphere/rpc");
    rpcRequestConfig.setTransport(AtmosphereRequestConfig.Transport.STREAMING);
    rpcRequestConfig.setFallbackTransport(AtmosphereRequestConfig.Transport.LONG_POLLING);
    final AtmosphereMessageHandler messageHandler = new AtmosphereMessageHandler() {

        public void onMessage(final AtmosphereResponse response) {
            List<ChatEvent> messages = response.getMessages();
            for (ChatEvent event : messages) {
                if (event.getStatus() == Status.LOGIN) {
                    if (!event.getUserName().equals(loginUser.getUserName())) {
                        pnlMessage.add(new HTML(TEMPLATES.notifyLoginUser(event.getUserName())));
                    }
                    ChatMembers.getChatMembers();
                }
                else if (event.getStatus() == Status.ONLINE) {
                    logger.info("received message through RPC: " + event.toString());
                    if (event.getUserName().equals(loginUser.getUserName())) {
                        pnlMessage.add(new HTML(TEMPLATES.getFormattedMessage(event.getUserName(),
                                SafeHtmlUtils.fromTrustedString(event.getMessage()), "myMessage")
                                .asString()));
                    }
                    else {
                        pnlMessage.add(new HTML(TEMPLATES.getFormattedMessage(event.getUserName(),
                                SafeHtmlUtils.fromTrustedString(event.getMessage()), "receivedMessage")
                                .asString()));
                    }
                }
                else if (event.getStatus() == Status.OFFLINE) {
                    pnlMessage.add(new HTML(TEMPLATES.notifyLogoutUser(event.getUserName())));
                    ChatMembers.getChatMembers();
                }

            }
            pnlScroll.scrollToBottom();
        }
    };

    rpcRequestConfig.setOpenHandler(new AtmosphereOpenHandler() {
        public void onOpen(final AtmosphereResponse response) {
            logger.info("RPC Connection opened");
            try {
                ChatEvent e = new ChatEvent(loginUser.getUserName(), txtInputMsg.getText(), Status.LOGIN);
                rpcRequest.push(e);
            }
            catch (SerializationException ex) {
                logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Failed to serialize message", ex);
            }
        }
    });

    rpcRequestConfig.setCloseHandler(new AtmosphereCloseHandler() {
        public void onClose(final AtmosphereResponse response) {
            logger.info("RPC Connection closed");
            try {
                ChatEvent e = new ChatEvent(loginUser.getUserName(), txtInputMsg.getText(), Status.OFFLINE);
                rpcRequest.push(e);
            }
            catch (SerializationException ex) {
                logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Failed to serialize message", ex);
            }
        }
    });

    rpcRequestConfig.setMessageHandler(messageHandler);
    Atmosphere atmosphere = Atmosphere.create();
    rpcRequest = atmosphere.subscribe(rpcRequestConfig);
}
```

> **EDITED** : show full codes but may contain un-nessary codes for actual problem.

But my **pnlMessage** was overflow and I can't get as I expected(*should be scroll*). I use [Atmosphere-GWT](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere-extensions/wiki/Atmosphere-GWT) for my chat program.

[image]

What am I wrong ? How can I fix it ? Thanks greatly.

Comment: It's working as expected for me. What version of GWT are you using?

Comment: @Braj I used 2.5 sir.

Comment: This is not actual code. From where cataclysm is coming in the snapshot? Please post actual code for sooner help. Have you tested the sample code that you have shared here?

Answer (score 0):

My problem is due to my CSS

```
pnlScroll.getElement().setAttribute("style", "border: 1px solid silver;"
        + "padding: 2px;margin-bottom: 5px;");
pnlScroll.setSize("400px", "420px");
```

I don't know why I loose `overflow: auto;` . After adding this css , my problem was fine.